# About the pluricanonical map of a surface of general type.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Reading an article by A.Beauville, i've found some facts about the pluricanonical map $\phi_{|nK_{X}|}$ of a surface $X$ of general type.
For example Bombieri showed that if $n\ge5  $ then $\phi_{|nK_{X}|}$ is an isomorphism outside some exceptional curves that are contracted into double rational points.
The application $\phi_{|3K_X|}$ is birational except two kind of surfaces described.
Finally $\phi_{|2K_X|}$ is birational except for surfaces that admits a curves bundle with genus $g=2$.
What about the application $\phi_{4K_X}$. Are there some results about it?

Comment: I believe Bombieri shows in the same paper that $4K$ is at least base-point free.

Comment: Without knowing anything, note that if $2K_X$ gives a birational map except in certain cases, then so must $4K_X$.